# Android studio: Emulate armeabi v7a 32bit on a 64bit intel cpu

Tags: android-studio, emulation

I want to test my app on a 32bit armeabi v7a device but I only have a 64bit phone. So I thought that I can emulate the device in android studio. Unfortunately the device is not even starting, there is an endless loop of "starting" after I try to launch it, there are no errors.

[image: Starting stuck]

I picked the api 24 image of armeabi v7a.

What's the problem with it?